# Invalid Operands to binary expression(const point and const point

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11

```
    map<pair<int,int>,int>pairOfNumbers;
pairOfNumbers.insert(pair<pair<int,int>,int>({1,2},2));
```

this is working, but

```
    map<pair<point,point>,int>PointsOnLine;
PointsOnLine.insert(pair<pair<point,point>,int>(make_pair(points[i],points[j]),count));
```

this doesn't.

point is just a structure of two ints x and y;
I keep getting the error 'Invalid Operands to binary expression(const point and const point' this is the structure of point.

```
    struct point
{
    int x;
    int y;
public:
    bool operator==(const point& p)
    {
        if(x==p.x && y==p.y)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    bool operator!=(const point& p)
    {
        if(x==p.x &&y==p.y)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
};
```

how do I insert two points and distance between them in the map?
in Xcode I get this error
[image: error message in Xcode]

Comment: count is integer

Comment: *"point is just a structure of two ints x and y"* - which you didn't include in your question, and it's relevant. Does `point` provide weak order comparison? It has to for that map to use a pair of them as a key. note: question would have  been answered had you posted a [mcve].

Comment: please post minimal reproducible example.

Comment: ^^^^ belongs properly formated [in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61136933/edit) as part of a [mcve].

Comment: sorry, updated the structure code. All that I need is how to insert two points and their distance ? and why is it working for int and not for Point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `point` type does not support weak-ordering. It has no method of determining is-less-than. You may think you don't need that because your `point` is actually tucked into a `std::pair<point,point>` but you do.

`std::pair<T1,T2>` supports weak ordering only if `T1` and `T2` do. In your case, they're the same type, so for a `std::pair<point,point>` to be used as key in a `std::map<std::pair<point,pint>,T>`, `point` must support weak ordering.

To support weak ordering, you must either provide an `operator<` that compares two of your objects in question, or a comparator functor type that does the same thing. The easiest way for you to do this would be:

```
#include <tuple>

struct point
{
    int x;
    int y;

    bool operator <(const point& p) const
    {
        return std::tie(x, y) < std::tie(p.x, p.y);
    }

    bool operator ==(const point& p) const
    {
        return !(*this < p || p < *this);
    }

    bool operator !=(const point& p) const
    {
        return *this < p || p < *this;
    }
};
```

I took liberty to redefine `operator ==` and `operator !=` to utilize the weak order properties of the proper `operator <`. It wasn't necessary, but ultimately it's just easier if operators root to as basic code as possible. With the above change you should be able to use both `point` and `std::pair<point,point>` as key types in `std::map` and `std::set`. In truth, a strict weak ordering can define *all* of the basic comparators  (<=, >, >=, !=, ==) as derivations from `operator <` in one form or another (or relative to something that does). I challenge you to consider them, try implementing them, and above all, writing some test harnesses that verify your implementation.